# java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: \target\output

Tags: java, file-io, io, nio

```
Path filePath = Paths.get(outputDir); "/target/output/"
Path file = null;
Path fileDir = null;

try {
    fileDir = Files.createDirectories(filePath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I keep getting the `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: \target\output` exception even if I delete the entire `target` directory and re-run. Could somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

The value of `outputDir` is being passed in from a property file and is:

`path.to.output=/target/output/`

I'm looking to create daily xml files in `/target/output` so only the first time it needs to create the directory.

Comment: Did you check `outputDir` with a debugger or `System.out.println`?

Comment: yes outputDir: "/target/output/" filePath:"\target\output"

Comment: Have you set a file name for the XMLs? For anything like this I include a timestamp in the file name down to the milllisecond to ensure there isn't a collision in naming

Comment: What OS are your working on?

Comment: I'm working on windows using IntelliJ idea

Comment: @MichaelWiggins I'm initially creating the directory fileDir, before constructing the file name for XML to `xmlFile = Paths.get(fileDir.toString(), dateToday+ ".XML");`

Comment: Maybe intelliJ Idea compiles your files in /target/output/ and locks the folder.  You delete it but when you start the application it recreates it